# How to spread three columns in CSS across a page equally

Tags: html, css

So I have looked at other questions on SE and from Google results but either they are too duct tape-y (using magic numbers, i.e. X amount of pixels in margin or padding or whatever,  which I don't like cause it's not scalable) or using methods that someone in some other search result says I shouldn't unless as a last resort (like float: left) or they are doing things I have done but which for whatever reason don't work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GDb</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen">    
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="NavBanner">
                <li><a class="Activatable" href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="Activatable" href="#">Search</a></li>
                <li><a class="Active" href="#">Browse</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="MainContent">
        <div class="Column">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <h1>By Genre</h1>
                <h2>Action</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Rainbow Six: Siege</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Adventure</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Sunless Sea</li>
                            <li>Alien: Isolation</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Strategy</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Stellaris
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>RPG</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="Column">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <h1>By Developer</h1>
                <h2>CD Projekt RED</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Creative Assembly</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Alien: Isolation</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Failbetter Games</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Sunless Sea</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Paradox Interactive</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Stellaris
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Ubisoft</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Rainbow Six: Siege</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="Column">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <h1>By Year</h1>
                <h2>2016</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Stellaris</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>2015</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Rainbow Six: Siege</li>
                            <li>Sunless Sea</li>
                            <li>The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>2014</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Alien: Isolation</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b3b3b0, #e3e2dd);
    background-color: #b3b3b0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.NavBanner
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

.Activatable
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.Activatable:hover:not(.active)
{
    background-color: #111;
}

.Active
{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.MainContent
{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    padding: 56px 14px 15px;
    width: 1700px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;

}

.Column
{
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.TextContainer
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

I almost have the desired result, but there is more space on the right of the right column than on the left of the left column as the columns aren't centered. I don't really care about the width or specific margin, padding or whatever of the columns, I just want them to be the same width and to be centered, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use flex :

You can simply test adding these 2 rules to your style sheet: (snippet below to see by yourself :) )

```
.MainContent {
  display: flex;
}

.Column {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b3b3b0, #e3e2dd);
  background-color: #b3b3b0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.NavBanner {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.Activatable {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.Activatable:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.Active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  cursor: default;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.MainContent {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 56px 14px 15px;
  width: 1700px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.Column {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  flex: 1;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.TextContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
    <nav>
            <ul class="NavBanner">
                <li><a class="Activatable" href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="Activatable" href="#">Search</a></li>
                <li><a class="Active" href="#">Browse</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="MainContent">
        <div class="Column">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <h1>By Genre</h1>
                <h2>Action</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Rainbow Six: Siege</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Adventure</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Sunless Sea</li>
                            <li>Alien: Isolation</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Strategy</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Stellaris
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>RPG</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="Column">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <h1>By Developer</h1>
                <h2>CD Projekt RED</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Creative Assembly</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Alien: Isolation</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Failbetter Games</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Sunless Sea</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Paradox Interactive</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Stellaris
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Ubisoft</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Rainbow Six: Siege</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="Column">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <h1>By Year</h1>
                <h2>2016</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Stellaris</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>2015</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Rainbow Six: Siege</li>
                            <li>Sunless Sea</li>
                            <li>The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>2014</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Alien: Isolation</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, hadn't understood what flex was or how to use it right.

Comment: @OddCore maybe these readings will be helpfull: https://www.sitepoint.com/are-we-ready-to-use-flexbox/  and https://www.sitepoint.com/easy-responsive-css-grid-layouts/ ?

Answer (score 1):

just add display:flex; in the parent container ( if not there then create 1) and in the child elements put flex:1; and they will occupy the full width of the parent..

Comment: Same answer as the one I accepted but since I can only accept one I upvote! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is very close to what you need to achieve your layout.

There are two minor but important changes.

First, to `.MainContent` add the rule `text-align: center` and this will center your the inline-block `.columns`.

Second, to get your text to flow normally, add `text-align: left` to `.column` (`text-align` is inherited).

Note: You can use `flex` but I (personally) always hesitate because of current browser support (though this is always getting better).

```css
body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b3b3b0, #e3e2dd);
  background-color: #b3b3b0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.NavBanner {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
.Activatable {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.Activatable:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}
.Active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  cursor: default;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.MainContent {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 56px 14px 15px;
  width: 1700px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.Column {
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.TextContainer {
 }
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="NavBanner">
      <li><a class="Activatable" href="Home.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="Activatable" href="#">Search</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="Active" href="#">Browse</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="MainContent">
  <div class="Column">
    <div class="TextContainer">
      <h1>By Genre</h1>
      <h2>Action</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Rainbow Six: Siege</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2>Adventure</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Sunless Sea</li>
          <li>Alien: Isolation</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2>Strategy</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            Stellaris
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2>RPG</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Column">
    <div class="TextContainer">
      <h1>By Developer</h1>
      <h2>CD Projekt RED</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2>Creative Assembly</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Alien: Isolation</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2>Failbetter Games</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Sunless Sea</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2>Paradox Interactive</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            Stellaris
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2>Ubisoft</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Rainbow Six: Siege</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Column">
    <div class="TextContainer">
      <h1>By Year</h1>
      <h2>2016</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Stellaris</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2>2015</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Rainbow Six: Siege</li>
          <li>Sunless Sea</li>
          <li>The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2>2014</h2>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Alien: Isolation</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvote for a way to do it other than flex! though I only need the first change you mentioned, I actually want the text to be left aligned but centered as it was before. What did you mean by current browser support, do not all current browsers support flex? Also, the one thing this method doesn't do that flex does is size the columns automatically to make them all equal.

Comment: I just checked out browser support at http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox and it appears that `flex` is supported across all modern browsers (post IE 9) so I would say it is now safe enough to use.  I first learned about flex 5 years ago when browser support was more limited, and I forgot to update my views on the matter!

Answer (score 1):

You have extra space to the right because each of the columns has a set width of 522px, but the container has a width of 1700px. The columns align to the left, leaving 134px of empty space.

A nice trick is to use `display: table` on the container of the columns and `display: table-cell` on the columns themselves. Then, set a width of 33.3333...% on each of the columns. This way, the width of the columns will be determined automatically and does not need to be hard-coded.

```css
body
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b3b3b0, #e3e2dd);
    background-color: #b3b3b0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.NavBanner
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

.Activatable
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.Activatable:hover:not(.active)
{
    background-color: #111;
}

.Active
{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.MainContent
{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    padding: 15px;
    width: 1700px;
    margin: auto;
    display: table;
}

.Column
{
    padding: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 33.333333%;
}

.TextContainer
{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.TextContainer h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GDb</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen">    
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="NavBanner">
                <li><a class="Activatable" href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="Activatable" href="#">Search</a></li>
                <li><a class="Active" href="#">Browse</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="MainContent">
        <div class="Column">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <h1>By Genre</h1>
                <h2>Action</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Rainbow Six: Siege</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Adventure</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Sunless Sea</li>
                            <li>Alien: Isolation</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Strategy</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Stellaris
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>RPG</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="Column">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <h1>By Developer</h1>
                <h2>CD Projekt RED</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Creative Assembly</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Alien: Isolation</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Failbetter Games</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Sunless Sea</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Paradox Interactive</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Stellaris
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>Ubisoft</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Rainbow Six: Siege</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="Column">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <h1>By Year</h1>
                <h2>2016</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Stellaris</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>2015</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Rainbow Six: Siege</li>
                            <li>Sunless Sea</li>
                            <li>The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <h2>2014</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Alien: Isolation</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Another good way to do what I wanted, doesn't add space between cells but is still useful!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using bootstrap?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="Column col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="Column col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="Column col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was told about bootstrap but since I am only now learning and I was told I need to know js for bootstrap, I am taking it step by step :)

Answer (score 0):

it will be easy if you go with bootstrap, just add bootstrap css files into your code and code like this:-

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```